# GIT: How to view various status graphs on self hosted GIT repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, gitweb

I am new to GIT. I have seen people telling lot of advantages of GIT over SVN. One of the advantages is, GIT provides nice visualizations so that you are updated with whats going in repository. I recently did lot of hands-on on GIT using Eclipse and found it really nice. I was using public repositories hosted on **GIT hub** to get a good understanding.

I have got my own server wherein I have a private GIT repository. My question is how can I get same set of visualizations on my hosted box?

Any package that needs to be installed for accessing GIT via a browser?

Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> GIT provides nice visualizations so that you are updated with whats going in repository

that's partly true:

```
git log --graph
```

will actually give you a nice looking ASCII-art graph, but that's nothing like the github visualizations.

Maybe you're looking for

```
gitg
```

or

```
gitk
```

which offer a graphical output.

If you want to have a web-based frontend, you'll need to install some git web frontend; https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Web_Interfaces lists a lot of these; what you'll need depends on so many factors including aesthetical preferences that I can't give a recommendation. You'll have to go through that list yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the advantages is, GIT provides nice visualizations so that you are updated with whats going in repository

While Git has **loads** of advantages over SVN, I never heard anyone claiming this.

The statistics are created by Github, not by Git.

Github *uses available information* from Git (who committed, when were the commits made, ...) and creates fancy graphs from this information.

If you want to have a web-based, self-hosted solution, the [Gitlab Community Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) would be a good choice. Gitlab has the ability to create similar graphs.

If you have no access to a linux box for hosting your Gitlab instance, there's a VM available at [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/virtual-machine) that could be used if you have only a Windows host.